# tensorflow, keras and circular import error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, plot, model

I'm trying my hand at replicating what this dude did on his github and trying to run some of his scripts (stock price prediction allegedly). I keep bumping into this error no matter what I do. I have a feeling I didn't set up tensorflow or keras properly.

```
File "/home/mihai/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/api/_v2/keras/utils/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    from keras.utils.vis_utils import plot_model
ImportError: cannot import name 'plot_model' from partially initialized module 'keras.utils.vis_utils' (most likely due to a circular import) (/home/mihai/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/utils/vis_utils.py)
```

Would appreciate any input!

Answer (score 0):

you can look here -> This worked taking from [TensorFlow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/plot_model)

try is also

```
from keras.utils.vis_utils import plot_model
```

or

```
from tensorflow.keras.utils import plot_model
```

Comment: I get the same error as before. I had tried looking in the tf documentation.